# Entity Framework and Nested Lambda Expressions

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I've just started using Lambda expressions, and really like the shortcut.  I also like the fact that I have scope within the lambda of the encompassing method.  One thing I am having trouble with is nesting lambdas.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
  MyContext context = new MyDomainContext();
  context.GetDocumentTypeCount(ci.CustomerId, io =>
  {
    if (io.HasError)
    {
       // Handle error
    }
    // Do some work here
    //         ...        
    // make DB call to get data
    EntityQuery<AppliedGlobalFilter> query =
      from a in context.GetAppliedGlobalFiltersQuery()
      where a.CustomerId == ci.CustomerId && a.FilterId == 1
      select a;

    context.Load<AppliedGlobalFilter>(query, lo =>
      {
        if (lo.HasError)
        {
        }

         **// Do more work in this nested lambda.  
         // Get compile time error here**

     }
                  }, null);
      }, null);


}
```

The second lambda is where I get the following compile time error:

Cannot convert Lambda expression to type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainService.Client.LoadBehavior' because it is not a delegate type

The compiler is choosing the wrong overload for the Load method even though I am using the same override I did in the previous Lambda.

Is this because I am trying to nest?  Or do I have something else wrong?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Sorry - I found the issue.  It had nothing to do with the nested lambda and everything to do with badly formated loops inside my Lambda.  It caused intelisense to go crazy and report a bogus error.  All is good with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem as described in my comment above.  I'll head back to work now - red face and all....

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not the answer you want, but I suggest caution about lengthy and/or nested lambdas.  They work, but they often make code harder to read / maintain by other developers.  I try to limit my lambdas in length to three statements, with no nesting.